# Maui App not working with Android Simulator namespace missing

Tags: visual-studio-2022, hybrid-mobile-app, maui, maui-blazor

I installed Visual Studio 2022 Preview Getting error when running Maui App using Android or Machine Simulator. Is anyone having the same issue?

**Already installed**

- Single-project MSIX Packaging
- Android device Manger

**Namespace missing if add the namespace still not working**

error "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MauiApp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   MauiApp37 (net6.0-android)"

Missing namespace if I include it still not working "using Microsoft.Maui.Hosting;"

[image]

**Second Error**

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1605  Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK from 1.0.0-preview3 to 1.0.0-experimental1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
MauiApp37 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui 6.0.101-preview.10.2068 -> Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK (>= 1.0.0-preview3)
MauiApp37 -> Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK (>= 1.0.0-experimental1)  MauiApp37

Answer (score 2):

Your main class is `MainApplication` of type `MauiApplication`

That means that the template that you used to create that project is old (I think it was preview 6 or 7)

If you create a new .NET MAUI App with a newer template, you will see that the main class is something like this. And it's the only main file

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

So I would recommend creating a new project using a new template, and then migrate the rest of the classes/views (use the same name for your project to make it easier)